# Terminal workflow shortcut

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete, textmate

I have all my code projects inside `~/Development/[subject]_dev/[project_folder]`

So for example my super-secret projects on **mutants > X-Weapon** is at:

`~/Development/mutants_dev/X-weapon`

I'd like to change in my project directory and open the project in **TextMate** from everywhere (any pwd) in my Shell.

Currently I have this in my `.bashrc`:

```
dev() { cd ~/Development/$1_dev/$2 && mate .; }
```

With this i type `dev mutants X-Weapon` and I start coding in **TextMate**.

However I'm not completely satisfied (I'm picky sometimes) and I would like to have TAB autocomplete for `$1` and `$2`. In other words i would like to hit tab and have the shell scope-search into my technologies (a.k.a folders inside Development) and then on my projects.

So for example: 
`dev mu[TAB]` becomes `dev mutants` and then `dev mutants X[TAB]` becomes... You get it.

Is it possible? How can i set the TAB context? THX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write your own completion function. Here is an example, which you can add to your bashrc.

```
_dev()
{
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    if [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 1 ]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(ls ~/dev)" -- $cur ) )
    elif [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 2 ]; then
        prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(ls ~/dev/$prev)" -- $cur ) )
    fi
}

dev() { 
    cd ~/dev/$1/$2 && mate .; 
}

complete -F _dev dev
```

**How it works:**

When you type `dev [TAB][TAB]`, the `_dev()` completion function is invoked. If you are trying to complete the first argument, it runs `ls` in the dev directory to get a list of all projects. If you are trying to complete the second argument, it runs `ls` within the project's directory.

For more information take a look at this tutorial: [Writing your own Bash Completion Function](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/04/writing-your-own-bash-completion.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use BDSM 'project' and project edit' functions for workflow navigation

Install bdsm as root (it installs to /usr/local/bdsm/) then in your user's profile,

```
EDITOR=mate ; export EDITOR
projects_path="$HOME/Development" ; export projects_path

# This loads the interactive bdsm shell functions like 'p' and 'pe'
# which reflect on the set $projects_path and EDITOR environment variables
if [[ -s "/usr/local/bdsm/modules/shell/project/interactive" ]]
  source "/usr/local/bdsm/modules/shell/project/interactive"
fi
```

Then in your terminal session you can quickly switch to the project,

```
~ $ p mu X
~/Development/mutants_dev/X-weapon/ $
```

OR, alternatively, you can both switch in the terminal and launch your EDITOR:

```
~ $ pe mu X
~/Development/mutants_dev/X-weapon/ $ # mate was also launched on the current directory
```

Note that it does prefix based matching, so the first matching prefix found first in the projects_path will be what is used. This is nice as it can greatly reduce typing. For example when I am working on BDSM itself I have ~/projects/bdsm/core and /extensions and I can respectively do,

```
~$ p bd c
~$ p bd e
```

(I cannot use simply 'p b c' here as I have a ~/projects/bash/ directory as well and that prefix would match first.)

p() and pe() should work in both bash/zsh, if it does not please let me know in #beginrescueend on irc.freenode.net.

Enjoy,

~Wayne

References
 - https://bdsm.beginrescueend.com/bdsm/install/
 - https://bdsm.beginrescueend.com/development/ # no need for core dev setup in *this* case.

Comment: Please note that the other answer answers the OP's bash tab question, I am answering the question from a workflow perspective instead for more/different information.